# Python Selenium как найти элемент <td> на Html при отстуствии его id и name

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Необходимо найти элемент  на HTML при отсуствии явного указания id и name ???
После нахождения selenium кликает по нему и все, но явно найти его никак не могу :(

Selenium ver 4.

```
element_td = driver.find_element(By.ID, value="Итоговое распределение").click()

... find_element(By.TAG_NAME, value="td")     # либо же по тэгу
```

[image: error_selenium]

Comment: Попробуйте по тексту в элементе найти https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323403/how-do-i-find-an-element-that-contains-specific-text-in-selenium-webdriver-pyth